# How can I make a Google DataStore database publicy readable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Datastore instance that contains public data. I want website users to query the database when they visit a particular url. Once the data is fetched, I'll use javascript to aggregate and display the data. It's a static site so I can't do this from a back end.

Is it possible to do this without creating a service account and using credentials? Cloud functions has the allUsers permission and I was hoping there is something similar for Datastore?

If it isn't possible to make the data public, I guess I could use a Cloud function. But I'd like to confirm there isn't a simpler solution first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a use case that's supported with Firestore in Native mode and the Firebase Web SDK ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-mobile-web)).

For Datastore, you are correct. You would need to use a something like a Cloud Function to make a back-end. By default, the Cloud Function [service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#runtime_service_account) has permission to access to a Datastore database in the same project.

Comment: I'd like to mark this as correct after editing. I cannot edit it myself. 

I do need to use a Cloud Function to make a back end, but a service account hasn't been required in my case. 

There could clearly be other situations where both a service account and a cloud function are required.

Comment: Updated the answer to note that a Cloud Function can access Datastore by default.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for a while I think that it is possible to make a Google DataStore database publicly readable, in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#all_authenticated_users) you will find an explanation of how to do that.

Best regards.